# Is it possible to perform an SQL query into an XML page?

Tags: sql, xml, report, odoo

I'm trying to edit an XML report which gather data from a table in database:

```
  <tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="l">
                    <td>
                       <span t-field="l.name"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       ...
                    </td>
                    ...
  </tr>
```

Now, this perfectly works and I'm able to print every field of the order_line table in my document. 
My problems start when i try to print a field of another table (product_template)

I'd like to print the result of the query:

```
SELECT product_template.product_code [this is NOT the product_id nor a primary key]
FROM product_template, order_line
WHERE
order_line.product_id = product_template.product_id;
```

This query returns a unic value, which is a string of 8 char and shoulc appear in a `<td> ... </td>` field of the document.

As I'm a beginner in xml coding and DB in general, any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dot notation like this:

```
<tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="l">
    <td>
        <span t-field="l.name"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span t-field="l.product_id.name"/>
        <span t-field="l.product_id.product_code"/>
    </td>

    <!-- [...] -->

</tr>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. 
I didn't understand how the dot notation works. Thank you very much

Comment: OK, you are welcome! Please mark the answer as correct to close the question